# PHP: Parse_url w/ preg_replace to remove portion of referrer URL string

Tags: php, preg-replace, parse-url

I'm trying to extract portions of a URL in PHP using `parse_url` and remove a portion of the `[path]` **if** it exists.

For example, if my URL is "http://localhost/website/section/type/name/" and I want to remove the `/website/` portion from the url `[path]`:

```
$url = wp_get_referer(); // using WordPress to get referring URL
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$parsed = preg_replace('/website/', '', $parsed[path]);
```

If I echo `$parsed` I get `//section/type/name/` as the result, whereas I'd like to return simply `section/type/name` as the result when "/website/" is present in the URL path string. How might I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace` is treating the `/` characters as the expression delimiter.

Since your search term is not a regular expression, you can simply use `str_replace` instead. Add in `rtrim` to remove the trailing slash.

```
$parsed = rtrim(str_replace('/website/', '', $parsed['path']), '/');
```

Note that I've also quoted the `path` parameter so as not to trigger an *"unknown constant"* notice

Comment: Ah! Ok thank you! Would `preg_replace` be required to remove a trailing slash if present?

Comment: @nickpish you can simply use `rtrim`. I'll add it to my answer